# how to use 2 on start in same activity?

Tags: android, webview

i have 2 on start function how can use both in same activity.
ist On start for deep link and 2nd onstart for notification link
 **1st Onstart**

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        try {
            String uriString = data.toString();
                if (uriString.contains("hin")) {
                uriString = uriString.replace("hin", "1");
            }
            webView.loadUrl(uriString);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

**2nd Onstart**

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        String webAdres = getIntent().getStringExtra("link"); //get link from firebase
        try {
            webView.loadUrl(webAdres);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have reputation for commenting, so posting comment as an answer:
Putting a String extra in the intent while calling activity from notification, and then checking the value of the extra in called activity should help you to differentiate the origin. Then you can use simple if-else...

add

`intent.putExtra("started_from","notification");`

to the code that starts the intent from the notifications, and the same thing to the other startActivity calls just change the value, then inside your activity

`String startedFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra("started_from");`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it this way

```
   @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        String webAdres = getIntent().getStringExtra("link"); //get link from firebase
        if (webAdres != null && !webAdres.isEmpty()) {
            webView.loadUrl(webAdres);
        } else {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            String uriString = data.toString();
            if (uriString.contains("hin")) {
                uriString = uriString.replace("hin", "1");
                webView.loadUrl(uriString);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {

}
    }
```